# Implementing Interfaces and calling Java Constants in Clojure (Newbie)

Tags: interface, clojure, java-interop

I am trying to write a wrapper for the google adwords api in Clojure but struggle with constants and Interfaces.
The java code looks like this :

```
CampaignServiceInterface campaignService =
    user.getService(AdWordsService.V201109.CAMPAIGN_SERVICE);
```

Usually you can call constants in Clojure with e.g. (Math/PI) but when I write:

```
(def user (AdWordsUser. ))
(.getService user (AdWordsService/V201109/CAMPAIGN_SERVICE))
```

I just get "no such namespace". 
Also I am a bit clueless on how to implement the interface correct. I think I should use "reify" but I get stuck.

Link to Interface:
http://google-api-adwords-java.googlecode.com/svn-history/r234/trunk/docs/com/google/api/adwords/v201003/cm/CampaignServiceInterface.html

```
(defn campaign-service [ ]
(reify 
  com.google.adwords.api.v201109.cm.CampaignServiceInterface
  (get [this] ??))))
```

Answer (score 4):

If I read it correctly, `AdWordsService.V201109.CAMPAIGN_SERVICE` is a static constant of an inner class of class AdWordsService.

To access inner classes you need to use java's internal name mangling scheme **; separate the inner class from its outer class with a $ sign:

`AdWordsService$V201109/CAMPAIGN_SERVICE`

** the JVM doesn't actually have a notion of inner classes, so java "fakes" it by creating a standalone class `AdWordsService$V201109`

Answer (score 1):

1.About accessing constants. Did you import `AdWordsService`? If not you either can access `AdWordsService` with fully qualified name: `some.package.name.AdWordsService/V201109/CAMPAIGN_SERVICE`, or import it via [import](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/import) macro.

2.Check examples here: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reify

```
(defn campaign-service [ ]
(reify   
  com.google.adwords.api.v201109.cm.CampaignServiceInterface
  (get [_ selector] (some-function selector))
  (mutate [_ operations] (some-function-2 operations))))
```

Comment: Hi Nikita, yes I imported it and I will try your way. Thanks for the interface example!